# Group list items to dict based on conditional delimiter as keys

Tags: python

I have this specific type of list that I want to convert into dict.

```
[In]: [1, 'a', 2, 3, 'b', 4, 5, 6, 'c', 7, 8, 9]
[Out]: {'a': [2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6], 'c': [7, 8, 9]}
```

If solution give rise to additional key to accommodate initial item (1 here), that's fine.

logic: group items based on string keys as delimiter.
original list contains same type of list with strings (for keys) but instead of numbers, it has html tags. But, solution to this problem should work there as well I believe.

This is what I tried that works. Not sure if the best solution.

```
d = {'a': [], 'b': [], 'c': []}

start = False
k = None
for n in l:
    if isinstance(n, str):
        start = True
        k = n
    elif start and k:
        d[k].append(n)
```

*Thanks*

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: It may not be clearly mentined but based on input and output that I want, it should be some what clear.  I additionally added example code to make it better.

Comment: Never mind. Thanks for your time to downvote. Keep up the good work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A basic one:

```
d = {}
a = []
for n in l:
    if isinstance(n, str):
        a = d[n] = []
    else:
        a.append(n)
```

Comment: Nice (+1). This is really simpler. Am I missing anything here or this is that simple?

Comment: @Rahul Not quite sure how to answer that :-). If there's anything to miss, I'd say it's that I temporarily collect initial numbers before the first string instead of throwing them away right away. That costs some memory, but simplifies the code a bit.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a helper generator to "unchain" your list based on type.

Then use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and a dictionary comprehension:

```
def unchain(l):
    k = None
    for i in l:
        if isinstance(i, str):
            k = i
        else:
            yield (k, i)
            
{k: [x[1] for x in g]
 for k,g in groupby(unchain(l), lambda x: x[0])}
```

output:

```
{None: [1], 'a': [2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6], 'c': [7, 8, 9]}
```

Without the first item if the list starts with a number:

```
{k: [x[1] for x in g]
 for k,g in groupby(unchain(l), lambda x: x[0]) if k}
# {'a': [2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6], 'c': [7, 8, 9]}
```

###### alternative: generator only

In this alternative, the list is build directly during iteration:

```
def unchain_to_dict(l):
    k = None
    vals = []
    for i in l:
        if isinstance(i, str):
            if k:
                yield (k, vals)
            k = i
            vals = []
        else:
            vals.append(i)
    yield (k, vals)

dict(unchain(l))
```

output:

```
{'a': [2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6], 'c': [7, 8, 9]}

# other example
dict(unchain_to_dict([1, 'a', 2, 3, 'b', 4, 5, 6, 'b2', 'c', 7, 8, 9, 'd']))
# {'a': [2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6], 'b2': [], 'c': [7, 8, 9], 'd': []}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Also using itertools

```
import itertools
X = [1, 'a', 2, 3, 'b', 4, 5, 6, 'c', 7, 8, 9]
Y = [i for i,j in enumerate(X) if isinstance(j, str)]
Z = {X[q[0]]:X[q[0]+1:q[1]] for q in itertools.zip_longest(Y,Y[1:])}
```

output:

```
{'a': [2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6], 'c': [7, 8, 9]}
```

Comment: Nice (+1), but this requires two iterations ;)